# Splitting a text file into integers in Python

Tags: python, list, split, integer

```
with open("data1.txt", newline='') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    s = list(r)

    dataList = []
```

I have a data file containing  rows of binary integers like this:

```
00000 0
00001 0
00010 0
```

etc.

I want to be able to split them all into individual integers so I get the exact same list but all split up into integers:

```
['0','0','0','0','0','0']
['0','0','0','0','1','0']
['0','0','0','1','0','0']
```

etc then append each one to dataList. So far I can split them up to the space in between them but that's it

Comment: Is there a blank line between each row of numbers?

Comment: No, they're all successive lines r. I'll try and correct that

Comment: For your sample file, how exactly should `dataList` look like in the end?

Comment: You still did not post a list. Also there are two `1` in the input, why are there three in the output?

Comment: It was an example. I just want to take the exact same values in the data file, split them up into individual integers and put them in an empty list in the same order in a row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably the simplest solution.  Remember that a string is iterable.

```
datalist = []
with open("data1.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.replace(" ", "")
        line_list = list(line.strip())
        datalist.append(line_list)
```

Comment: This is basically the same solution as timgeb posted but I chose to split it on multiple lines for readability.

Comment: This will have newline characters.

Comment: Why are you throwing away the result of `line.replace(" ", "")` ?

Answer (score 2):

`list(string)` will give you a list of the characters in the string.

Assuming data1.txt as

```
00000 0
00001 0
00010 0
```

you can write

```
with open('data1.txt') as f: 
    result = [list(line.strip().replace(' ', '')) for line in f]
```

to get

```
>>> result                                                                 
[['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
 ['0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0'],
 ['0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0']]
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex will work:

```
import re
digits = "000001"
re.sub(r'([0-9])(?!$)', r'\1,', digits)
```

Instead of digits above just pass every line of your file

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a 3rd party library, you can do this with Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

x = StringIO("""00000 0
00001 0
00010 0""")

# replace x with 'file.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(x, delim_whitespace=True, dtype=object, header=None)

res = [[*x, y] for x, y in df.values]
```

Result:

```
[['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
 ['0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0'],
 ['0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0']]
```